# Is というもの just for emphasis?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, words

For example:

> 私は自分の時間というものをほとんど持っていない。
>   私は自分の時間をほとんど持っていない。

I'm pretty sure both are correct but is there any difference between both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「私は自分{じぶん}の時間{じかん}**というもの**をほとんど持{も}っていない。」
>
> 「私は自分の時間をほとんど持っていない。」

「～～というもの」 is indeed used for emphasis by calling attention to the preceding word/noun.  It does not, however, change the basic meaning of the sentence much.

The nuance of the first sentence above is similar to that of saying "I have very little spare time." with the "spare time" part finger-quoted.

Comment: heh... I imagine an English speaker conveying the same idea would say something like     "Free time"? (snort) What's that??

Comment: @ericfromabeno Sorry, I don't understand.. "Spare time" "free time" are both used to mean 暇(な時間)、自由な時間 or 自分の時間, no? イギリスの先生には "in your spare time" って習ったけど・・ "spare time"って変なんですか？

Comment: @Chocolate, sorry, I wasn't implying that "spare time" was wrong. To me they are interchangeable, so I changed it without even thinking.

Comment: @ericfromabeno あ、わかりました・・すみません。